# Vaadin 8 + AudioVideo Addon: "Failed to load the widgetset"

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin8

I added the [AudioVideo Addon](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/audiovideo) to my Vaadin 8 (version 8.7.2, Maven 3, Tomcat) project and everything woks fine in my Eclipse development environment (I did run Maven clean install). But if I export the WAR file to the deployment server the app fails to start with the following error:

```
Failed to load the widgetset: ./VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset/AppWidgetset.nocache.js?1556793473728
```

I found the following in my Maven POM:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I think I need to change something in the Maven config. I tried the "packagingIncludes" instead of "packagingExcludes" but this did not help.

I would be glad for your help since I cannot do "experiments" on the deployment server.

How do I have to configure Maven or what else do I have to do to get the following folder from the eclipse depolyment environment into my exported WAR file?

`myApp\target\myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\VAADIN\widgetsets\AppWidgetset`

Comment: Have you recompiled the widgetset?

Comment: I added the mvn code for the addon and then I did mvn update project and then clean install in my development environment. How to recompile the widgetset?

Comment: If you have project based on normal Vaadin archetype, the "mvn install" command should compile widgetset. You should anyway check if you have vaadin-maven-plugin defined in there. Also when you run "mvn install" check if there is any errors in the compilation.